# How to change dashboard settings in OBIEE?

Tags: excel, obiee

I am completely new to OBIEE.
When I try to export a chart inside a dashboard to excel 2007, I am not able to see the download prompt box. So where can I change the settings to achieve this?

Once set the path, the file should get downloaded when exported to excel 2007 without asking the prompt. Is it possible in OBIEE?

Answer (score 0):

The automatic download is controlled at the browser level.

If using Firefox, you can delete or modify the default download behavior by file type.

Chrome uses a more simplistic approach: it just downloads to the destination set as your Download folder in your Chrome settings.